# Inconsistent Video Conversion

Tags: php, command-line, ffmpeg, exec

I have a script calling a command to run an ffmpeg conversion on an uploaded video. It works only at random times however. Sometimes the form will finish submitting and the ffmpeg process will be running; at other times, the ffmpeg command fails to run at all. Here is the command that I'm running in an exec() function:

```
ffmpeg -i  "uploaded_file -b 450k  "converted_file" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Can anyone explain why this will only work on certain tries and not on others?

Comment: Can we please see your actual code? It might be a problem with your PHP rather than with the external command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if ffmpeg fails and throws and error? Right now you're sending all output to `/dev/null` so you'll never know.

Change `>/dev/null` into `>>/tmp/ffmpeglog`  to keep a log

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.